# Is a planetary 'temperature inversion' plausible?

Tags: science-based, planets, atmosphere

It was disputed in the 1940s-50s whether Venus

1. had a hot surface and cool cloud layer or
2. a cool surface and hot cloud layer.

As I recall, both were considered at the limits of plausibility at the time. We know that Venus turned out to be case 1.

But is case 2 still a plausible type of planet, with some other atmospheric conditions?

Bonus: Can you make this inversion such that the surface isn't just cooler than the atmosphere, but cooler than a vacuum world would be?

Edit: Not a complete answer, but I just came across https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-greenhouse_effect That said, I already knew that some phenomena (IE, atmospheric particulates) could raise albedo and thus cool the planet. What that page does not explicitly answer is...

A. Can / does a high-albedo atmospheric layer (one that would be noticeable from space as a 'surface', unlike Earth's ozone layer) have a higher temperature than the surface?

B. Is it plausible to have a natural atmosphere where the anti-greenhouse effect dominates over any greenhouse effect that's likely also present? Wiki article says this is *not* the case for Titan.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the atmosphere is transparent to most of the radiation coming from a star, and thus the only way for the atmosphere to be heated up is by heat exchange with the surface of the planet, absorbing the radiation and re-emitting it at lower frequencies.

This is why the temperature decreases with increasing the height above the sea level on Earth.

If you want to have an higher layer at a higher temperature than the ground you need to have a heat source. Since you cannot rely on stellar radiation, your other option is some exothermic chemical reaction.

For example, again on our planet, $2 \ O_3 \ \vec \  \ 3 \ O_2$ releases energy and keep the [stratosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratosphere) at higher temperature, preventing its mixing with the troposphere.

> The stratosphere is stratified in temperature, with warmer layers higher and cooler layers closer to the Earth; this increase of temperature with altitude is a result of the absorption of the Sun's ultraviolet radiation by the ozone layer.

Comment: Not really what I was thinking of. My main interest is whether you can create an anti-greenhouse-effect.

Comment: By 'anti-greenhouse', do you mean the opposite of Earth's current greenhouse effect?

Comment: Look at my original post: "cooler than a vacuum world would be". Basically, an atmosphere that blocks more heat from reaching the surface than it traps.